# Length of Array in Object doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I'm trying to use the tree hierarchy in D3 and got stuck.  I thought I'm building the JSON correctly but when I looked at the object in Developer's Tool, I see the following:

[image: chrome]

Notice the first line shows the dependents array has 0 length but when expanded, you can clearly see dependents has 3 objects.  When I stringify it, I get the following:

```
{"attributes":{"id":0,"name":"root"},"dependents":[]}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is wrong. They represent a view of the object at different times. The latter is likely a later view. This view has no impact on your code.

Comment: ...in other words, you probably are building it correctly. Just don't rely too heavily on  representations in developer tools.

Answer (score 6):

This problem usually happens when you change the object after having logged it because Chrome doesn't deep-copy the object when you log it but simply stores a reference.

The tree isn't immediately built but only when needed and sometimes it's based on a more recent value.

If your object is light enough, you can clone it yourself if you really want to see the value at logging time :

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myobject)));
```

If your object is big or recursive, you may find it a little more difficult to clone it. Personally I have my own tool, [JSON.prune.log](http://dystroy.org/JSON.prune/).

As ignoring the browser's optimization comes with a cost, you should most often simply take into account this behavior and log only primitive if you want to be sure of their logging time value...

Comment: I suppose when I call the `nodes` function, it's getting the object before the changes had taken place, just like how Chrome isn't getting the most up-to-date object.  How do I address that?